# Python print statement--wrinting into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw this piece of code in a book and when I try to implement it I get a invalid syntax error.

This code basically reads a dictionary and writes into a txt file..

main.py

```
from Basics import data

dbfilename = 'people-file'
ENDDB  = 'enddb.'
ENDREC = 'endrec.'
RECSEP = '=>'


def storelist(db,dbfilename):
    print('In storelist function')
    dbfile = open(dbfilename, 'w')
    for key in db:
        print(key, file=dbfile)


    dbfile.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('In Main list-items=',data.people)
    storelist(data.people,dbfilename)
    #for key in data.people:   
    #   print('Values are', key['name'])
```

data.py

```
bob={'name':'bobs mith','age':42,'salary':5000,'job':'software'}
sue={'name':'sue more','age':30,'salary':3000,'job':'hardware'}

people={}
people['bob'] = bob
people['sue'] = sue
```

Error:

Syntax error:Invalid syntax.

Is it possible to write a file using a print statement.

Comment: _Where_ did you get that syntax error?

Comment: are you using python 2.x or python 3.x?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're really using python from the 2.x family. Print is a [builtin function in python 3 and a statement in python 2](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html). What happens if you try to print to a file using the [2.x syntax](http://stefaanlippens.net/redirect_python_print)?

```
 print >>dbFile, key
```

To check your version, open an interactive python shell and do

```
 sys.version_info
```

I have 2.7, so I get

```
 sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Comment: I got this from the Oreily book..they are trying to print the message..not write into a file..still I get a error with the print statement.

Comment: @user1050619: No, they are trying to write it to a file, using the print statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could just change it from using print to `dbfile.write(key + "\n")`. It is easier to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on python 2.6 or newer, you can try adding

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore it..Its just a print statement..Its not  a write statetement..I will delete this thread so that folks are not confused.